# glfwInit taking a long time to initialize

Tags: c++, visual-studio, glfw

It used to work fine last week but now that I'm trying to open the project again, it stays stuck on `glfwInit()` for a good 30 second every time. I've tried it using both a project on VS2015 and the new 2017 one to see if it fixed it.

There's nothing before `glfwInit();` and when I put a breakpoint right after, it takes 30 seconds to break.

I can't seem to find anything on this, is there any known solution?

Answer (score 2):

*Reboot.*

I was having this same problem, and it immediately went away once I rebooted my PC.

Comment: Reboot didn't fix it for me.

Comment: Reboot fixed it for me. Thanks!

Comment: But the problems comes back if the computer stays on for some time. Its not convenient to have to reboot it over and over again. What could be the reason behind this? How can I fix this without having to reboot?